# Poisson distribution for electricity blackout during a week with parameter $\lambda=10.5$

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I want to calculate the probability that at least in one day of the week there is more than one blackout that occurred on the same day.
Secondly if it is known that at least in one day of the week a blackout occurred ,what is the probability that on Sunday occurred more than one blackout ?

For the first part i thought it was fairly simple by calculating $P\{X>0\}=1-F_X(0)$ where $F_X(0)=P\{X\leq0\}$ but then i thought it doesnt make since since that will be equaly to $1$ so my approach is wrong here.

For the second part can i go on and say that $P\{$For a blackout to occur on Sunday$\}=\frac{1}{7}$ and since the blackouts on days are independent then by the conditional probability

$P\{$A=Blackout on Sunday | B=More than one blackout occurred on same day$\}=\frac{\frac{1}{7}P(B)}{\frac{1}{7}}$

Comment: I don't quite get what the hypotheses are. Can you further elaborate the requirements in the body of the question?

Comment: I have further elaborated for the first part that is confusing me on how to calculate

Comment: If I get it right, though, you may consider using a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda/7$ and then a Bernoulli distribution over the entire week...

Comment: Perhaps the first part is equal to the probability to get more than one blackout on the same day out of 7 days? But i'm not sure on how to do that is it $1/7$ for a blackout to be on one day?

Comment: @Matteo would you explain to me further on why you took $\lambda/7$ , I have just studied the Poisson distribution and I'm trying to understand on how to approach problems of this kind as much as possible

Comment: I'll write down some hints in a second if nobody does in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming $\lambda=\frac{21}{2}$ is the average number of blackouts in a week.

Then, the average number of blackouts in one day is just $\frac{\lambda}{7}=\frac{3}{2}$, since it is a Poisson process, and thus the average number of events is proportional to the observation interval.

So if you let $X$ be the number of blackouts in a day, then
$$P(X=k)= e^{-3/2}\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k}{k!}, \ \ k=0,1,2,\dots,$$
and the probability of having more than one blackout in one day is
$$p=1-P(X\leq 1)= 1- P(X=0)-P(X=1)=1-\frac{5}{2}e^{-3/2}.$$

Now, getting to the week, let $Y$ be the number of days in which you have more than one blackout. $Y$ has a Binomial distribution with parameters $n=7$ and $p$ given by the previous equation. So

$$P(Y=k)={7\choose k} p^k(1-p)^{7-k}, \ \ 0\leq k \leq 7,$$
and the answer to your question is
$$P(Y\geq 1) = 1-P(Y=0)=1-(1-p)^7=1-\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^7e^{-21/2}.$$

Comment: Why is $\lambda=11/2$ now ,is it an example ?

Comment: @user3133165 sorry, I typo... corrected.

Comment: @user3133165 I added some numbers; have a look and let me know if it looks fine to you.

Comment: I'm looking at the Poisson distribution table in my book "probability and statistics for computer scientists", And by that table $P\{X\leq1\}=0$ is this correct? because i'm not certain .

Comment: @ as you write it, it is not. This would imply that the event must occur at least twice... Which does not make sense, does it?

Comment: No it does not but i'm trying to make sense of the table, shouldn't the result be the same?. The table is the calculation of $F(x)=P\{X\leq x \}=\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^k}{k!}$

Comment: @user3133165 just put $x=1$ in that expression. You don't get $0$, of course.

Comment: Never mind I was looking at the case where $\lambda=10.5$

Comment: @user3133165 the form of expression you wrote does not depend on $\lambda$... you don't get $0$ anyhow...

Comment: I now have a better understanding of this problem. I still want to try and solve the second part of the problem, now this has to do with conditional probability ?

Comment: @user3133165 exactly, but recall that the Poisson process is memoryless!

Comment: I have edited the body of the question,do you think my approach for the second part is correct?

Comment: @user3133165 the notation is a bit confusing. You may want to use the fact the that the probability of **more than one** backout occuring on **any** day is just $p$...